# translating sql to codeigniter db

Tags: php, codeigniter

can someone can help me to translate it to codeigniter db query

```
SELECT COUNT(SALES_NO),shop_fc_no  
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(SALES_NO) AS SALES_NO,MIN(SEQ) AS SEQ,shop_fc_no
  FROM TBL_FOOD_ORDER 
  WHERE shop_fc_no = '99997' AND 
        check_flg =0
  GROUP BY SALES_NO,SEQ) AS a
```

So far I've come up with

```
$this->db->select('SHOP_FC_NO, count(SALES_NO) AS ORDER_COUNT'); 
$this->db->from('TBL_FOOD_ORDER'); 
$this->db->where('SHOP_FC_NO',$shop_fc_no); 
$this->db->where('CHECK_FLG = 0'); 
$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: $this->db->select('SHOP_FC_NO, count(SALES_NO) AS ORDER_COUNT');

$this->db->from('TBL_FOOD_ORDER');

$this->db->where('SHOP_FC_NO',$shop_fc_no);
$this->db->where('CHECK_FLG = 0');
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();

Comment: Next time, edit your question and do not comment. Way better to read due to formatting options, I did that for you right now.